# Words are not printed in the file

Tags: python

I have this project which is information search systems.
I have an array called Corpus and I want to read the words from it and extract the irregular verbs from it and save it to another file.
I have another matrix containing irregular verbs.
I compared the two matrices and extracted the regular verbs and saved them in a file called "irregular_verbs".

But the problem is when the program is executed nothing is printed in the file "irregular_verbs".

Inside this file I called the corpus array in order to pass it and compare it with the array of regular verbs and if the verb is irregular it is put in the file "irregular_verbs".

second_request.py:

```
from firstRequest import read_corpus_file_and_delete_stop_words;

corpus = read_corpus_file_and_delete_stop_words();
# print(corpus)

z = []
irregular_verbs = []


def read_irregular_verbs():
    with open('C:/Users/Super/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/Files/irregular_verbs.txt', 'r') as file:
        for line in file:
            for word in line.split():
                irregular_verbs.append(word)

    return irregular_verbs


# print(read_irregular_verbs())


irregular_verbs_file = []


def access_irregular_verbs():
    irregular_verbs_list = read_irregular_verbs()
    for t in irregular_verbs_list:
        for words in corpus:
            for word in words:
                if t != word[0]:
                    continue
                else:
                    with open('../Files/irregular_verbs_output.txt', 'a+') as irregular_file:
                        irregular_file.write(t)

    return irregular_verbs_list


print(access_irregular_verbs())
```

Through this file, I went to a folder named Corpus that contains many files and I saved the elements of these lists in an array.

first.py:

```
def read_corpus_file_and_delete_stop_words():
    stop_words_list = stopwords.words('english')
    additional_stopwords = []

    with open("C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Lab4/IR Homework/stop words.txt", 'r') as file:
        for word in file:
            word = word.split('\n')
            additional_stopwords.append(word[0])

    stop_words_list += additional_stopwords

    dir_path = 'C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Lab4/corpus/corpus/'
    # save_dir = "C:/Users/Super/Desktop/IR/homework/Files_Without_SW/"

    files_without_sw = []
    for document in os.listdir(dir_path):
        with open(dir_path + document, "r") as reader:
            # save_file = open(save_dir + document, 'w')
            text = reader.read()

            text = text.replace('.', ' ').replace(',', ' ')
            text = text.replace(':', ' '). replace('?', ' ').replace('!', ' ')
            text = text.replace('  ', ' ')  # convert double space into single space
            text = text.replace('"', ' ').replace('``', ' ')
            text = text.strip()  # remove space at the end

            text_tokens = word_tokenize(text)
            tokens_without_sw = [word for word in text_tokens if
                                 (word not in stop_words_list)]
            # save_file.writelines(["%s " % item for item in tokens_without_sw])
            # print(document, ':', tokens_without_sw)
            files_without_sw.append(tokens_without_sw)

    return files_without_sw


print(read_corpus_file_and_delete_stop_words())
```